# Need Get-VM progress

Tags: powershell, while-loop, do-while, powercli

We have a very large environment therefore it takes around 5 mins to collect all of the VMs  and store them into a variable. I need a way to display progress until this collection is complete. I figured a `do until` loop would work, however I cant quite figure it out.

This is the direction I was heading, not sure if its right though.

```
do {
    write-host "."
    $VMs = get-VM
}
while ($VMs.Count ++ )
```

My thought was it was write dots until the VMs count stopped, but this is not the case. Any help with would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$VMS = get-VM | %{ write-host .; $_}
```

Also, have a look at using `Write-Progress`. It is meant to be used in such scenarios.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347663.aspx

Comment: I looked into Write-Progress, but it looks like I need to have vm count beforehand which means still waiting for to collect all of them, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @jrob24 - Yeah, that is why I gave the other solution as well. I was just saying that, write-progress is the general way for doing this.